# Word и jasperreports: большие пробелы в тексте

Tags: java, ms-word, jasperreports

Имеется отчет, в котором требуется задать для TextField свойство "Выровнять текст по ширине",

в текстовке используется html разметка и имеются переносы (`<br>`).

Текстовка идет в таком формате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самом jasperreports (окошко предпросмотр) это выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При формировании word документа получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какие-то способы не разбивая поле на несколько мелких с разным выравниванием, сохранить расстановку и переносы в тексте и избавиться от огромных пробелов?

Спасибо!

**UPDATE**

если в ворд для переноса использовать вот такой символ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то все хорошо переносится и никаких пробелов,

но проблема остается, т.к неясно как сделать чтобы ворд (jasper) воспринимал `<br>` или `\n` как этот символ.

вместо этого ворд интерпретирует их как :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение:

Если для переноса использовать пару tab+newline (`&#9;<br>` в HTML или `\t\n` в Java),
то таб прижимает текст "до" к левому краю, а текст после так и остается распределенным по ширине экрана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]